# After woocommerce update “-” and “+” quantity buttons doesn't enable cart update button

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

In my theme I have a custom quantity-form.php where I added two buttons that change product quantity. When I go to cart page the -,+ buttons change the quantity but the update cart button doesn't get enabled. If I change the quantity value via keyboard, update cart buttons gets enabled. I use the woocommerce pluggin.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help someone as this question was asked 1 year before.

This will remove the disabled property for the update button on page load, ajax and quantity dropdown changed.

ref : https://gist.github.com/mikaelz/f41e29c6a99a595602e4

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script', 1000);
function cart_update_qty_script() {
    if (is_cart()) :
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            // Enable update cart button upon successful ajax call
            $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
            $( 'div.woocommerce > form input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
        });
        // Enable update cart button on initial page load
        $( 'div.woocommerce > form input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', false );

        // Update cart when quantity pulldown is changed
        $('body').on('change', '#quantity_pulldown', function () {
                       var quantity_selected = $("#quantity_pulldown option:selected").val();
               $('#product_quantity').val(quantity_selected);

               jQuery("[name='update_cart']").removeAttr('disabled');
               jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");

           });

    });

      </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```